# Retrieving Tktinter Entry Values where GUI is Variable

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have Tkinter GUI with some entry boxes, and a button at the bottom that I want to click to retrieve the values from the boxes.

The tricky part is, that the number of entry boxes in my GUI is not fixed.

Earlier in my code I generate a list and the number of items in this list is the number of entry boxes I am generating, using the following:

```
from tkinter import *

...

root = Tk()

root.title('Title')

title_label = Label(root, text="Inputs", font=("Helvetica", 14)).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady="8")

idx = 0
for i in list:
    globals()['label%s' % idx] = Label(root, text=i).grid(row=(idx+1), column=0, sticky=W, padx=12)
    globals()['entry%s' % idx] = Entry(root, text=i).grid(row=(idx+1), column=1, sticky=W, padx=12)
    idx += 1

upload_prices = Button(root, text="Upload Prices").grid(row=16, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Now I'm a little bit stuck however, because I'm struggling to defind a command function which is also variable in order to use .get() on each of my "entry0, entry1, entry2" boxes - however many there are. I have tried:

```
from tkinter import *

...

root = Tk()

root.title('Title')

title_label = Label(root, text="Inputs", font=("Helvetica", 14))
title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady="8")

def upload_prices():
    global alist
    for i in range(len(alist)):
        globals()['entry_get' + str(i)] = globals()['entry%s' % i].get()

idx = 0
for i in alist:
    globals()['label%s' % idx] = Label(root, text=i)
    globals()['label%s' % idx].grid(row=(idx+1), column=0, sticky=W, padx=12)
    globals()['entry%s' % idx] = Entry(root, text=i)
    globals()['entry%s' % idx].grid(row=(idx+1), column=1, sticky=W, padx=12)
    idx += 1

upload_prices_button = Button(root, text="Upload Prices", command=upload_prices)
upload_prices_button.grid(row=16, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to remove `.grid(...)` from `Label(...).grid(...)` and `Entry(...).grid(...)`.

Comment: Why are you storing/accessing `globals()` like that...?

Comment: You shouldn't use `globals()` like this. Just use a normal dictionary or list to store the widgets. Your code will be much easier to write, read, and debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you define the entries like so:

```
idx = 0
for i in list:
    globals()['label%s' % idx] = Label(root, text=i).grid(row=(idx+1), column=0, sticky=W, padx=12)
    globals()['entry%s' % idx] = Entry(root, text=i).grid(row=(idx+1), column=1, sticky=W, padx=12)
    idx += 1
```

You need to get the values in the same way so:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    globals()["entry_get" + str(i)] = globals()['entry%s' % i].get()
```

This will save entry 1 to `entry_get1` and so on.

If you want to save them to abc etc. you can do:

```
idx = 0
for i in 'abcdefghijklmno':
    globals()[i] = globals()['entry%s' % idx].get()
    idx+=1
```

Your function could look like this:

```
def upload_prices():
    global list
    for i in range(len(list)):
        globals()['entry_get' + str(i)] = globals()['entry%s' % i].get()
```

I would not recommend using the `list` keyword as a variable though.

Also, `upload_prices` is a button and function, that will prove not good. change one or the other like so:

```
upload_prices_button = Button(root, text="Upload Prices", command=upload_prices)
upload_prices_button.grid(row=16, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
```

You also cannot define and grid the entries at the same time so here is the full working code:

```
from tkinter import *

...

root = Tk()

root.title('Title')

title_label = Label(root, text="Inputs", font=("Helvetica", 14))
title_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, pady="8")

My_list = [i for i in range(10)]

def upload_prices():
    for i in range(len(My_list)):
        globals()['entry_get' + str(i)] = globals()['entry ' + str(i)].get()

idx = 0
for i in My_list:
    globals()['label ' + str(idx)] = Label(root, text=i)
    globals()['label ' + str(idx)].grid(row=(idx+1), column=0, sticky=W, padx=12)
    globals()['entry ' + str(idx)] = Entry(root, text=i)
    globals()['entry ' + str(idx)].grid(row=(idx+1), column=1, sticky=W, padx=12)
    print(globals()['entry ' + str(idx)])
    idx += 1

upload_prices_button = Button(root, text="Upload Prices", command=upload_prices)
upload_prices_button.grid(row=16, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

NOTE: I changed `list` to `My_list`.

Another point: I would recommend you a dictionary instead of `globals()`:

```
My_Dict["entry" + str(i)] = Entry()
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have the following error -

    globals['entry_get' + str(i)] = globals()['entry%s' % i].get()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'

Please see my edit with your addition under the def upload_prices()

Can you advise?

Comment: @SlowlyLearning It should be `globals()["entry_get" + str(i)]` not `globals["entry_get" + str(i)]` I think it was a copy/paste error.

Comment: @SlowlyLearning I updated my answer with an example function.

Comment: Just make sure `list` is defined.

Comment: @SlowlyLearning please see my full code block I tested it and it works.

Comment: It is better to use a normal dictionary instead of `globals()`.

Comment: @acw1668 I agree, I was just editing what he had rather than re-coding everything.

Comment: For me it's not working. It's still showing the global variables has NoneTypes, now when applying the grids -

    globals()['label%s' % idx].grid(row=(idx+1), column=0, sticky=W, padx=12)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'grid'

Comment: @SlowlyLearning I do not have `['label%s' % idx]` in my code so you still must not copied correctly.

Comment: @SlowlyLearning Use the full code that I posted.

Comment: Is there a reason why you had to `for i in My_list:` and create a list just for that? You could have done `for i in range(10):` too.

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria the OP is using a list of something for a reason but since it was not shared in the question I had to make a dummy list to take it's place. In his case I assume `My_list` will not just contain a range of numbers.